# How to convert .img to .tar to flash using Samsung odin tool?

Tags: recovery-mode, samsung, odin

I have downloaded touch recovery from [clockworkmod website](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager). How do I flash downloaded .img file using Odin / Mobile Odin tool?

Comment: where do i fine that recovery.img file? Link please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the answer from [XDA Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=35239060&postcount=10).

In linux or windows with cygwin.

```
$ tar -H ustar -c recovery.img > recovery.tar
$ md5sum -t recovery.tar >> recovery.tar
$ mv recovery.tar recovery.tar.md5
```

Comment: where do i fine that recovery.img file? Link please