# Samsung Galaxy S3 cannot be accessed by pc after root

Tags: usb, superuser, kingo

I did this to my samsung galaxy s3 and it cannot be accessed by a pc using usb.

- Rooted android 4.2.2 using kingo root
- Installed TWRP
- Installed LiquidSmooth for galaxy s3
- Installed GAPS
- Apparently LiquidSmooth comes with SuperUser
- Tried unrooting
- Soft-bricked my device
- Factory Reseted
- Still cannot find phone on pc

Can anybody help?

Comment: Did you swipe down the notification bar to see if "USB Charging Only" was selected and not "MTP Mode" (not quite sure if it is worded this way, gotta be close)?

Comment: Recently, I had a problem that flashing CMMod failed, so my OS was missing. Will the answer to my question be useful to you? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132033/recover-android-system-with-twrp-recovery Also, some ROMs (like CM) come with a built-in root function, so you cannot unroot them, but you can just not enable or disable the root function

Comment: It doesn't show.