# Can we backup the stock recovery.img in any way?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, stock-rom

Suppose I plan to flash my recovery with TWRP/CWM, but then later suppose I would like to move back to the stock recovery. 
Is it possible to take a backup of stock recovery just like we can take a backup of our ROM?

Comment: Check this universal thread: **[Making Dump of Android Partitions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2450045)**. Just backup the recovery.img from there

Comment: Why do you you think it won't be possible? Rashr, Flashify and `dd` are always there to help as long as you've root access.

Answer (score 10):

**EXTRACTING BOOT.IMG FROM STOCK ROM or OTHER IMG LIKE RECOVERY ETC.**

**REQUIREMENT:**
1. Download **adb** required tools.
2. PC
3. Phone Drivers (for other phones google it out)
          for spreadtrum phones: SCI-Usb-Jungo v4 [(download here)](http://adf.ly/cT9ke) or
                SCI-USB2Serial v1.5.6.1 [(download here)](http://adf.ly/cT9rT)
4. Android Phone + Usb cables

**STEPS:**
OPEN cmd window in adb folder

type the ff:

```
      adb devices 
      adb shell
      su 
      cat /proc/mtd
```

Now from your screen look at your files and you see **mtd10 has your recovery.img**

```
dev: size erasesize name 
mtd0: 00040000 00020000 "misc" 
mtd10: 00500000 00020000 "recovery"
mtd12: 00280000 00020000 "boot"
mtd13: 04380000 00020000 "system"
mtd14: 04380000 00020000 "cache"
mtd15: 04ac0000 00020000 "userdata"
```

[image]
Once u see it's **LOCATION** in which in this sample is in mtd10
type:

cat /dev/mtd/mtd10 > /sdcard/mtd10.img **or** 
cat /dev/mtd/mtd10 > /sdcard/recovery.img 
*Source:* http://howtorootcherrymobilesnap.weebly.com/adb/how-to-extract-img-files-via-adb-ex-bootimg

Comment: **/proc/mtd** is not universal. It's not there in all devices.. Change it :)

Comment: But works in many devices.

Comment: /proc/mtd is not there in my device (Yuphoria). It's empty in my mom's device (Android One).

Comment: And you conveniently didn't mention the [original source](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22EXTRACTING+BOOT.IMG+FROM+STOCK+ROM+or+OTHER+IMG+LIKE+RECOVERY%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=uYl6VuKqOIOUuAT1npqgDg). Please follow [How to reference material written by others](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Comment: /proc/mtd not found in my lenovo device. This may work  on certain devices only.

Comment: While `/proc/mtd` may not be valid for all devices how would anyone know trying to answer this question without first being provided what device model number/name is being worked on? This answer is good and until the question's author can provide specs I don't think I'd do any better than Vivek Ji already has. Also Firelord suggestions on `dd` will also work great for doing full backups over USB.

Comment: there is no /proc/mtd in samsung t-2111, please specify your device model to make this answer more clearly

Comment: The OP wanted to make a backup of the recovery partition BEFORE flashing a custom recovery partition. The custom recovery is needed to get root access `su`. So these commands will only work when the stock recovery partition is already gone.

Answer (score 5):

## Generic Backup/ Restore

If you are root you can backup/ restore all partitions (not only recovery) with native tools.

To list all mountable partitions and block devices use `find` and `grep`

```
adb shell
su
find /dev | grep by-name$
```

On my system I get `/dev/block/platform/soc/1d84000.ufshc/by-name` back (this is very device specific and yours may look different).

Now You can list `ls` this path to show all mountable partitions.

```
ls -al --color /dev/block/platform/soc/1d84000.ufshc/by-name/
```

Or all in one command

```
ls -al --color $(find /dev|grep by-name$)
```

### Backup

Armed with this information you can, as root, backup all partitions. Just use the `dd` (part of every android toolboox/ toyboox e.g.:

```
dd if=/dev/block/platform/soc/1d84000.ufshc/by-name/recovery of=/sdcard/Download/recovery.img.dd
```

### Restore

> **Warning**
>   Data lost possible! Don't use until You understand all `dd` parameter.

In many cases you can also **restore** with the `dd` tool, e.g:

```
dd if=/sdcard/Download/recovery.img.dd of=/dev/block/platform/soc/1d84000.ufshc/recovery
```

Answer (score 3):

The key point is to boot a custom recovery partition such as TWRP **without installing it**. For instance with an HTC device you would use the platform adb tools and run this command from a terminal in Windows:

```
fastboot boot twrp.img
```

This remote-boots the custom recovery partition so you leave the stock recovery partition intact.

Now you root the phone.

Reboot the phone.

adb shell

su

Use dd command to copy the recovery partition.

If you have already flashed a recovery partition then it's too late. You will have to find a stock recovery partition for your phone somewhere on the [interweb](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interweb).